# AG Grid: Framework component is missing the method getValue() in production build but not development

Tags: vue.js, vite

We have defined a checkbox editor for ag-grid like this:

```html
<template>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { ICellEditorParams } from "ag-grid-community";
import { ref } from "vue";
type Props = {
  params: ICellEditorParams;
};

const props = defineProps<Props>();
const checked = ref(props.params.value);
const getValue = () => checked.value;

defineExpose({
  getValue,
});
</script>
```

When running `npm run dev` we see the following build output. The ag-grid works. No problems. Good!

[image]

When running `npm run build && npm run preview` we see the following build output. The ag-grid complains about a missing `getValue()`.

[image]

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559836/ag-grid-framework-component-is-missing-the-method-getvalue-vue3-composition-a) established a probably root cause:

> ag-grid properly works with functions directly returned from setup() function and haven't access to functions returned via exposed context properties

So, how can we make our `vite` production build *return* the `getValue` in the same what that the development build does?

Answer (score 2):

Until either Vite or ag-grid support using `defineExpose()`, this workaround returns `getValue()` to ag-grid by using `<script>` instead of `<script setup>`.

```html
<template>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import type { ICellEditorParams } from "ag-grid-community";
import { ref } from "vue";
type Props = {
  params: ICellEditorParams;
};

export default {
  setup(props: Props) {
    const checked = ref(props.params.value?.valueOf());
    console.log("wat", checked.value);
    return {
      checked,
      getValue: () => checked.value,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue!
I fixed by change composition to options,
I created a custom range component that set and get in the same AG grid schema type.

[image]

```html
<template>
  <div class="ag-filter-toolpanel-instance-body ag-filter">
    <div class="ag-filter-toolpanel-instance-filter">
      <div class="ag-filter">
        <form class="ag-filter-wrapper ag-focus-managed" @submit.prevent="handleApply">
          <div class="ag-filter-body-wrapper ag-simple-filter-body-wrapper" style="">
            <!-- Operation |  between : ------------------------------------------------>
            <div class="ag-picker-field ag-labeled ag-label-align-left ag-select ag-filter-select" role="presentation">
              <div
                aria-controls="ag-select-list-274"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Filtering operator"
                class="ag-wrapper ag-picker-field-wrapper ag-picker-has-focus ag-picker-collapsed"
                tabindex="0"
              >
                <div class="ag-picker-field-display">Between</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div aria-hidden="false" class="ag-filter-body" role="presentation">
              <!-- Fields |  From : ---------------------------------------------------->

              <div
                aria-hidden="false"
                class="ag-labeled ag-label-align-left ag-number-field ag-input-field ag-filter-from ag-filter-filter"
                role="presentation"
              >
                <div class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-number-field-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                  <input
                    v-model="fromVal"
                    aria-label="Filter from value"
                    class="ag-input-field-input ag-number-field-input"
                    placeholder="From"
                    step="any"
                    tabindex="0"
                    type="number"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Operation |  To : ---------------------------------------------------->

              <div
                aria-hidden="false"
                class="ag-labeled ag-label-align-left ag-number-field ag-input-field ag-filter-to ag-filter-filter"
                role="presentation"
              >
                <div class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-number-field-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                  <input
                    v-model="toVal"
                    aria-label="Filter to Value"
                    class="ag-input-field-input ag-number-field-input"
                    placeholder="To"
                    step="any"
                    tabindex="0"
                    type="number"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Actions  : ---------------------------------------------------------->
          <div class="ag-filter-apply-panel">
            <button class="ag-button ag-standard-button ag-filter-apply-panel-button" type="submit">Apply</button>
            <button
              class="ag-button ag-standard-button ag-filter-apply-panel-button"
              type="button"
              @click="handleClear"
            >
              Reset
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    params: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      localValue: null,
      fromVal: null,
      toVal: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isFilterActive() {
      return this.localValue !== null;
      // return this.localValue !== null && this.localValue !== undefined && Object.keys(this.localValue).length === 0;
    },
    getModel() {
      if (!this.isFilterActive()) {
        return null;
      }
      return this.localValue;
    },
    setModel(model) {
      if (!model && (!model?.value?.filter || !model?.value?.filterTo)) {
        this.localValue = null;
        this.fromVal = null;
        this.toVal = null;
      } else {
        this.fromVal = model?.value?.filter;
        this.toVal = model?.value?.filterTo || null;
        this.localValue = {
          filter: this.fromVal || 1,
          filterTo: this.toVal || null,
          filterType: 'number',
          type: 'inRange'
        };
      }
    },
    handleApply() {
      this.localValue = {
        filter: this.fromVal || 1,
        filterTo: this.toVal || null,
        filterType: 'number',
        type: 'inRange'
      };
      this.params && this.params.filterChangedCallback();
    },
    handleClear() {
      this.localValue = null;
      this.fromVal = null;
      this.toVal = null;
      this.setModel(null);
      this.params && this.params.filterChangedCallback();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```